# Autogenerate Console Output for Roxygen @examples Section

Tags: r, r-markdown, documentation-generation, roxygen2, code-documentation

## Background

I am documenting an R package, and I wish the [`@examples`](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd.html#examples) section(s) to include the (commented) output below the code, so the user need not run the examples (in the console, etc.) in order to see the output.

As such, I have typed the output (`#> ...`) by hand...

```r
#' @name my_topic
#' 
#' @title My Topic
#' @description A page for the general topic, under which the specific function(s) will appear.
#' @export
#' 
#' @examples
#'   # Demo variables available throughout the topic.
#'   unnamed_vec <- 1:3
#'   unnamed_vec
#'   #> [1] 1 2 3
#'   
#'   named_vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
#'   named_vec
#'   #> a b c
#'   #> 1 2 3



#' @rdname my_topic
#' @export
#' 
#' @param x An \R object.
#' 
#' @details `my_fun()` is an alias for [base::names()].
#' 
#' @return For `my_fun()`, a `character` vector with the names, or `NULL` if no names are found.
#' 
#' @examples
#'   
#'   
#'   
#'   # An application of `my_fun()` specifically.
#'   my_fun(unnamed_vec)
#'   #> NULL
#'   
#'   my_fun(named_vec)
#'   #> [1] "a" "b" "c"
my_fun <- function(x) {
  base::names(x)
}
```

...in order to yield the following page in the manual:

> ### My Topic
>
> ###### Description
>
> A page for the general topic, under which the specific function(s) will appear.
>
> ###### Usage
>
> `my_fun(x)`
>
> ###### Arguments
>
> `x` An **`R`** object.
>
> ###### Details
>
> `my_fun()` is an alias for [`base::names()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/names.html).
>
> ###### Value
>
> For `my_fun()`, a `character` vector with the names, or `NULL` if no names are found.
>
> ###### Examples
>
> ```
> # Demo variables available throughout the topic.
> unnamed_vec <- 1:3
> unnamed_vec
> #> [1] 1 2 3
>
> named_vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
> named_vec
> #> a b c
> #> 1 2 3
>
>
>
> # An application of `my_fun()` specifically.
> my_fun(unnamed_vec)
> #> NULL
>
> my_fun(named_vec)
> #> [1] "a" "b" "c"
> ```

## Goal

Instead of typing this output (`#> ...`) by hand, I want it to **autogenerate from the executable code**, so changes to the commands (`my_fun(...)`) are dynamically reflected in the output.

I hope to outsource this to R markdown, as with [code chunks](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd-formatting.html#code-chunks) suggested by [**`roxygen2`**](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/index.html):

> ### Code chunks
>
> You can insert executable code with ```` ```{r} ````, just like in knitr documents. For example:
>
> ````
> #' @title Title
> #' @details Details
> #' ```{r lorem}
> #' 1+1
> #' ```
> #' @md
> foo <- function() NULL
> ````

### Note

I see the [*website*](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/index.html) for the [**`purrr`**](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/index.html) package seems to autogenerate output for its [**Examples**](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html#ref-examples)

> ### Examples
>
> ```
> # Reducing `+` computes the sum of a vector while reducing `*`
> # computes the product:
> 1:3 |> reduce(`+`)
> #> [1] 6
> 1:10 |> reduce(`*`)
> #> [1] 3628800
> ```

from the executable code under its `@examples` [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/fd5a7320e37f7301c2dcc1668d032ee0d35acc9c/R/reduce.R#L72-L125):

> ```
> #' @examples
> #' # Reducing `+` computes the sum of a vector while reducing `*`
> #' # computes the product:
> #' 1:3 |> reduce(`+`)
> #' 1:10 |> reduce(`*`)
> ```

However, this output does *not* appear on the corresponding **Help** page in RStudio:

> ###### Examples
>
> ```
> # Reducing `+` computes the sum of a vector while reducing `*`
> # computes the product:
> 1:3 |> reduce(`+`)
> 1:10 |> reduce(`*`)
> ```

## Problem

Unfortunately, when I try to implement code chunks under `@examples`...

````r
#' @examples
#' ```{r}
#' # Demo variables available throughout the topic.
#' unnamed_vec <- 1:3
#' unnamed_vec
#' 
#' named_vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
#' named_vec
#' ```
````

````r
#' @examples
#' ```{r}
#' 
#' 
#' # An application of `my_fun()` specifically.
#' my_fun(unnamed_vec)
#' 
#' my_fun(named_vec)
#' ```
````

...I **do *not* get the intended result** (below) for the manual:

> ###### Examples
>
> ```
> # Demo variables available throughout the topic.
> unnamed_vec <- 1:3
> unnamed_vec
> #> [1] 1 2 3
>
> named_vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
> named_vec
> #> a b c
> #> 1 2 3
>
>
>
> # An application of `my_fun()` specifically.
> my_fun(unnamed_vec)
> #> NULL
>
> my_fun(named_vec)
> #> [1] "a" "b" "c"
> ```

Instead, my [`check()`](https://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/check.html) **triggers the following error**:

````
── R CMD check results ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── pkg 0.0.0.9000 ────
Duration: 18.5s

❯ checking examples ... ERROR
  Running examples in ‘my_topic-Ex.R’ failed
  The error most likely occurred in:
  
  > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > ### Name: my_topic
  > ### Title: My Topic
  > ### Aliases: my_topic my_fun
  > 
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  >   ```{r}
  Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
  Execution halted

❯ checking for unstated dependencies in examples ... WARNING
  Warning: parse error in file 'lines':
  attempt to use zero-length variable name

1 error ✖ | 1 warning ✖ | 0 notes ✔
````

### Note

I have tried to force markdown with the [`@md`](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/reference/tags-rd-formatting.html) tag...

```r
#' @md
#' @examples
```

...but the error still occurs.

Unfortunately, I suspect that *everything* under the `@examples` tag is automatically [treated and executed as pure R code](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd.html#examples), and *never* as R markdown.  So the result is not the `.Rd` below...

```
 \examples{
 Examples
 
 if{html}{\out{<div class="sourceCode r">}}\preformatted{
 # Demo variables available throughout the topic.
 unnamed_vec <- 1:3
 unnamed_vec
 #> [1] 1 2 3
 
 named_vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
 named_vec
 #> a b c
 #> 1 2 3
 
 
 
 # An application of `my_fun()` specifically.
 my_fun(unnamed_vec)
 #> NULL
 
 my_fun(named_vec)
 #> [1] "a" "b" "c"
 }\if{html}{\out{</div>}}
 }
```

...but rather an attempt to execute this code in R *itself*...

````
 ```{r}
 # Demo variables available throughout the topic.
 unnamed_vec <- 1:3
 unnamed_vec
 
 named_vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
 named_vec
 ```
 ```{r}
 
 
 
 # An application of `my_fun()` specifically.
 my_fun(unnamed_vec)
 
 my_fun(named_vec)
 ```
````

...before rendering (something like) the `.Rd` below:

````
 \examples{
 Examples
 
 \preformatted{
 ```{r}
 # Demo variables available throughout the topic.
 unnamed_vec <- 1:3
 unnamed_vec
 
 named_vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
 named_vec
 ```
 ```{r}
 
 
 
 # An application of `my_fun()` specifically.
 my_fun(unnamed_vec)
 
 my_fun(named_vec)
 ```
 }
 }
````

Naturally, trying to execute the first line in R...

````
 ```{r}
````

...will yield an error, since the symbol ```` ``` ```` represents a "zero-length variable name":

````
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  >   ```{r}
  Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
  Execution halted
````

## Question

**What is the canonical way to autogenerate console output for the executable code in `@examples`?**

I would like to *avoid* hacking together a fake **Examples** section like so:

````r
#' @md
#' @section Examples:
#' ```{r}
#' # Demo variables available throughout the topic.
#' unnamed_vec <- 1:3
#' unnamed_vec
#' 
#' named_vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
#' named_vec
#' ```
````

Comment: `pkgdown::build_reference` is probably a good place to start, but I'm not convinced that there is a way to inject the output into the corresponding Rd files. You might have to do that part of the text processing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own with `parse_Rd` and `Rd2ex` from **tools**.  I've written a rough version here, where `rdfile` and `con` are paths or text mode connections to Rd files (the input and output) and `comment` is the prefix for all output lines inside of `\examples{}`.

Notably, I haven't tried to divert messages or warnings along with example output, but that can in principle be done by establishing suitable calling handlers before evaluating example code.

```r
withExOutput <- function(rdfile, con = stdout(), comment = "## ") {
    ## Parse Rd file
    rd <- tools::parse_Rd(rdfile)

    ## Write example code to *.R
    exfile <- tempfile()
    on.exit(unlink(exfile))
    tools::Rd2ex(rd, out = exfile)

    ## Determine number of lines in 'Rd2ex' header
    exfile.con <- file(exfile, open = "r")
    skip <- 1L
    while (length(zzz <- readLines(exfile.con, n = 1L)) &&
           !length(grep("^### \\*\\*", zzz)))
        skip <- skip + 1L
    while (length(zzz <- readLines(exfile.con, n = 1L)) &&
           !nzchar(zzz))
        skip <- skip + 1L
    close(exfile.con)

    ## Run examples without header and capture stdout/stderr
    x <- capture.output(source(
        exfile, local = new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv),
        echo = TRUE, spaced = FALSE, verbose = FALSE,
        prompt.echo = "~~~~> ", continue.echo = "~~~~+ ",
        skip.echo = skip))

    ## Strip source prompts, comment output lines
    prompted <- grep("^~~~~[>+] ", x)
    x[ prompted] <- sub("^~~~~[>+] ", "", x[prompted])
    x[-prompted] <- paste0(comment, x[-prompted])

    ## Replace \dontrun{}, \dontshow{}, \donttest{}
    s1 <- c("## Not run: ",    "## End(Not run)",
            "## Don't show: ", "## End(Don't show)",
            "## No test: ",    "## End(No test)")
    s2 <- c("\\dontrun{",      "}",
            "\\dontshow{",     "}",
            "\\donttest{",     "}")
    mx <- match(x, s1, 0L)
    x[mx > 0L] <- s2[mx]

    ## Uncomment lines inside of \dontrun{}
    x <- sub("^##D ", "", x)

    ## Delete trailing empty lines
    n <- length(x)
    while (n && !nzchar(x[n]))
        n <- n - 1L
    x <- x[seq_len(n)]

    ## Replace old \examples{} with new {including output}
    rdfile <- tempfile()
    on.exit(unlink(rdfile), add = TRUE)
    writeLines(c("\\examples{", x, "}"), rdfile)
    tags <- vapply(rd, attr, "", "Rd_tag")
    rd[tags == "\\examples"] <- tools::parse_Rd(rdfile)[1L]

    cat(as.character(rd), file = con, sep = "")
}
```

Taking any Rd file as an example:

```latex
%% this is add.Rd
\name{add}
\alias{add}
\title{Add two numbers}
\description{Computes \code{a + b} given \code{a} and \code{b}.}
\usage{
add(a, b)
}
\arguments{
  \item{a}{A number.}
  \item{b}{Another number.}
}
\examples{
(a <- 0)
add(a, 1)
\dontrun{
add(a, 2)
}
\dontshow{
add(a, 3)
}
\donttest{
add(a, 4)
}
}
```

You would attach your package with `library`, then call `withExOutput` with suitable arguments (e.g., probably ensuring that `comment` starts with a `#`):

```r
add <- function(a, b) a + b # simulating a 'library' call
withExOutput("add.Rd", comment = "#> ") # in the style of 'reprex'
```

When you accept the default `con = stdout()`, the "new" Rd file with example output is just printed in your console (assuming that you haven't diverted it somewhere else):

```latex
%% this is add.Rd
\name{add}
\alias{add}
\title{Add two numbers}
\description{Computes \code{a + b} given \code{a} and \code{b}.}
\usage{
add(a, b)
}
\arguments{
  \item{a}{A number.}
  \item{b}{Another number.}
}
\examples{
(a <- 0)
#> [1] 0
add(a, 1)
#> [1] 1
\dontrun{
add(a, 2)
}
\dontshow{
add(a, 3)
#> [1] 3
}
\donttest{
add(a, 4)
#> [1] 4
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Mikael, thank you for your custom solution!  I've been too busy to test this, so I haven't yet marked it correct.  But yours is the only answer, and I didn't want your hard work to go to waste, so I have awarded the bounty for now.  I will comment here with any further updates from its use with my package.  :)